# simple form association radio buttons include_blank

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

How can I include a blank option using simple_form radio_buttons?

`include_blank` does not work with radio_buttons:

```
= f.association :location, as: :radio_buttons, collection: @locations, include_blank: "any location"
```

[image]

But works without them

```
= f.association :location, collection: @locations, include_blank: "any location"
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder. Line 97-100. They said `include_blank` option is applicable for some inputs such as **date, datetime, select**.

Comment: FormBuilder#collection_radio_buttons is the one that you are looking for

Comment: https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/issues/1690